# System.Data missing in F# project

Tags: f#, system.data

I'm targeting .NET 3.5, but cannot get System.Data to come up in Intellisense. What am I missing?

Comment: Funny thing is that I can open it just fine in FSI, but I cannot compile the code from my .fs file.

Comment: +1 as a one time bonus for your avatar.  I can taste your Zuuuuunnnnne.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is 'by design' and not a bug in F#. By default the project templates we ship (in Visual Studio 2010) add the following references:

- mscorlib.dll - Things like 'string'
- FSharp.Core.dll - All things F#
- System.dll - Things like System.IO
- System.Core.dll - .NET 3.5 additions, like HashSet<_>
- System.Numerics.dll - For F#'s BigInteger type

For any specific libraries like ADO.NET, WPF, WCF, etc. you will need to add the specific assembly references you need.

Answer (score 1):

Had to add a reference. I guess I was too used to the C# template doing this for me.